# Discord.py sending messages in every server except one

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot that will listen to one specific channel in a server, then repeat anything said in that channel to a specific channel of every other server the bot is apart of. I'm struggling to get the bot to repeat any text to other servers. Here's the code

```
server = str(message.guild.id)
channel = str(message.channel.id)

message = message.author.name+': '+message.content
for servers in client.guilds:
    if str(servers.id) not in [server]:
        for channels in servers.channels:
            if str(channels.id) in os.listdir(path+'servers/'+str(servers.id)):
                await bot.send_message(channels, message)
```

Comment: are there errors or is it just not working?

Comment: it's not raising any errors, but still isn't sending any messages

Comment: What version of `discord.py` are you running? You can check by doing something along the lines of `print(discord.__version__)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `<channel>.send(<message>)` instead of `bot.send_message(<channels>, <message>)`. To do that, you need to get the `channel` object.

```py
server = str(message.guild.id)
channel = str(message.channel.id)

message = message.author.name+': '+message.content
for servers in client.guilds:
    if str(servers.id) not in [server]:
        for channels in servers.channels:
            if str(channels.id) in os.listdir(path+'servers/'+str(servers.id)):
                _channel = bot.get_channel(int(channels.id))
                await _channel.send(message)
```